# Sikuli: How to click on each excel cells specific interval of time?

Tags: excel, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script

I am new to Sikuli. I need to click on each excel cell - one by one of the specific interval of time so how can I iterate among the excel cells.

[image: As shown in picture]

**Update 1:**
 When mouse click on the 1st cell of a hyperlink(i.e. google.com) and specific interval of time again mouse click on the 2nd cell of the hyper link(i.e. gmail.com) and so on till the end of the cell.

**Update 2:**
Actually, I have an excel file - In the file, specific Single column - I want to click on all hyperlink continuously using Sikuli?
My question not about time interval but my question is how to click on all hyperlink one by one.

Comment: Click with what? Mouse? Keyboard? If mouse, what button? What are you asking exactly? The excel part or the clicking part? Please add some more information to your question

Comment: see Update 1 in question section, Thanks

Comment: So you are asking about how to insert intervals? Are you using Sikuli with Jython or Java?

Comment: Please see Update 2 in question section @EugeneS., Thanks and Fine with any one(Jython or Java).

Comment: Have you tried something and it didn't work? Can you share what you tried? Do you have a basic understanding how Sikuli works? If not, I suggest look at some examples first. You can start here: http://www.sikuli.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a few steps.

First locate the image of the 'A' field. 
Then define that region below it.

To find an image you could use:

```
imageA = ("A.png")
columnA = find(imageA).below()
```

You also have `.left()` for example.

If you use `.hightlight(5)` you can see what region Sikuli takes. 
But only use that to debug, I had problems with clicking on a field after using that in the code.

You can do 2 things then. 
1. Define the region for image of number 1 but then with a left, and where they match you click. 
2) Now you know the region where column A starts you could click below it every x pixels.

But I suggest option 1.

Comment: if dynamically change A.png then what is possibility?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about inserting time intervals, you can just utilize the tools of the programming language you are you are using. For example in Jython(Python):

```
import time

print("before sleeping")
time.sleep(5) # sleep/wait for 5 seconds
print("after sleeping")
```

In Java:

```
Thread.sleep(5000); // sleep for 5000ms which is 5sec
```

Comment: Thanks for your time..! but Actually I have a excel file - In the file, specific Single column - i want to click on all hyper link continuously using Sikuli? My question not about time interval but my question is how to click on all hyper link one by one